Plotting the phase portrait of a time-dependent ODE
I have an equation for a damped harmonic oscillator which I've reduced to these equations:
$$x = e^{-t} \cos(3t)$$
$$\dot{x} = e^{-t} (-\cos(3t) - 3 \sin(3t))$$
I'd like to plot the solutions using StreamPlot, but that only accepts functions of coordinates. Is there a way to convert the time-dependent equations to location-dependent ones?
